# the_posts_pagination doesn't work in wordpress main page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

In my main index.php file I have this code and I want to show the pagination on my page so I call the_posts_pagination() function but it won't work.

```
<?php 
get_header();
if ( have_posts() ) {
   while (have_posts()) {
       the_post();
?>
       <div class="container">
           <div class="mb-5 post">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-8">
                       <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" type="<?php the_title_attribute();?>">
                          <?php the_title();?>
                       </a>
                       <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
                       <div class="post__data">
                           <div class="post__data--author">
                               <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')) ?>">
                                   <?php echo get_the_author();?>
                               </a>
                           </div>
                           <div class="post__data--date">
                               <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">
                                  <time datetime="<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>">
                                      <?php echo get_the_date();?>
                                  </time>
                               </a>
                           </div>
                           <div class="post__data--readMore">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink();?>">
                                    Read More
                                </a>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
<?php } 
the_posts_pagination(  ); ?>

<?php } else { ?>
<p>Sorry No posts avliable</p>
<?php } ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[image: This is the index.php result]

I'm a beginner in WordPress so please if I did any mistake asking the question then sorry.

Comment: This will be more helpful for you : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174907/how-to-use-the-posts-navigation-for-wp-query-and-get-posts

Answer (score 0):

`the_posts_pagination()` work only on archive pages. Use paginate_links with correct arguments for with.

Comment: I'm learning from a Udemy course and the instructor did the same and work but for me, it won't work. And what is an archive page?

Comment: you can see word press structure from : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Here is screenshot of template-hierarchy : https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png